# Can ListItem leadingContent be top aligned in Jetpack Compose Material3?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-material3

`ListItem` has been added to M3, but the `leadingContent` is centered vertically. Is there a way to align it at the top?

```kotlin
    ListItem(
        leadingContent = {
            AvatarView(avatar = friend.avatar, size = 40, modifier = modifier) {
                onClick(0)
            }
        },
         headlineText = {
            Text(text = friend.name,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(bottom = 8.dp)
                    .wrapContentWidth(align = Alignment.Start)
                    .then(modifier))
        },
        supportingText = {
            Text(text = friend.bio + "", modifier = Modifier
                .padding(bottom = 16.dp)
                .then(modifier))
        },
        modifier = Modifier.clickable { onClick(0) }
    )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [M3 specs guideline](https://m3.material.io/components/lists/specs#583e3432-0dc0-4a18-bfb4-a0924f67891b), the `leadingContent` has `contentAlignment = Alignment.TopStart` only with the **Three-Line List Item**.
You can achieve it adding an empty `overlineText` attribute with `overlineText = {  }`.

Something like:

```
ListItem(
    headlineText = { Text("Two line list item with empty overlineText") },
    supportingText = { Text("Secondary text") },
    overlineText = {  },
    leadingContent = {
        Icon(
            Icons.Filled.Favorite,
            contentDescription = "Localized description",
        )
    }
)
```

[image]

---

[**Specs guidelines:**](https://m3.material.io/components/lists/specs#eeeb78e0-265d-4e81-96ba-c2340c348a90)

Two-line lists:
[image]
Three-line lists:
[image]

Comment: Sir saw your answer many times, you are really great